# Why `cmd /k` and `cmd /c` remember the history of already finished cmd sub-processes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here're the command I've executed:

```
>cmd /k
>echo 1
1

>echo 2
2

>echo 3
3

>exit /b

>cmd /c "doskey /history"
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
exit /b

>
```

(tested on windows 7x64) According tho the process explorer the `cmd /k` starts a sub-process (not a thread). So after process is exited I would expect that it will clear his things from the memory. This thing happens on 3/4/.. spawned cmds , `for /f` , with called batch file.

Comment: Short version: it is the console window, not the command shell, that is doing the work here.

Comment: See also  [doskey history behaviour across cmd instances](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7782)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short version:

The console window handles the command history

## Detailed:

The processes of a command prompt window is as follows:

> conhost.exe
>   --- doskey.exe
>   ------ cmd.exe
>   --------- any sub-processes (In your case `cmd /k`)

**As on [Microsoft technet:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks)**

> ... If you exit and then restart a program from the same Command Prompt window, **the command history from the previous program session is available.**
>   
>   You must run Doskey.exe before you start a program. You cannot use doskey command-line options from a program's command prompt, even if the program has a shell command.

`Doskey` is executed under `conhost.exe`, the process that displays the command prompt window. This enables it to monitor keystrokes for **all sub-processes and threads**.

When you call cmd from within another process, **the root CMD process handles the doskey history**

**Update:**

As commented by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd), in Windows XP/2003/Vista/2008 the command history is handled by `csrss.exe`. From Windows 7 upwards, `conhost.exe` handles the command history - more [here](http://www.rekall-forensic.com/docs/Manual/Plugins/Windows/CmdScan.html)

Comment: Just for information, for windows XP/2003/Vista/2008 the command history is handled by `csrss.exe`. From windows 7 `conhost.exe` handles this task (more [here](http://www.rekall-forensic.com/docs/Manual/Plugins/Windows/CmdScan.html)).

Comment: But why the history is unchanged for the first `cmd.exe` just under `doskey.exe`? But when you open again a new `cmd` then there is the _full_ list of all entered commands

Comment: No, it's more complicated, see [doskey history behaviour across cmd instances](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7782). There are stored at least two different lists